# UILongPressGestureRecognizer and UITextField don't work together

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIViewController with a LongPressGesturerecognizer attached. 
There is also a UITextField in the view controllers view.

If I tap on the UITextField, the Gesturerecognizer catches the long press. Copy, paste, cursor oving is not possible.

I would like to have the Gesturerecognizer be active anywhere in the view except the UITextField, where I would like the default OS behaviour like copy, paste, move the cursor etc.

Is that possible? Can I somehow tell the gesture recognizer to forward the gesture to the UITextFields default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set a delegate to your `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and implement the `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` delegate method like this:

```
- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return touch.view != self.textField;
}
```